# Why can't django's reverse() match an email parameter?

Tags: python, django

I'm using a DRF ViewSet to manage user accounts:

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'email'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

And have a testcase like:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from .base import BaseApiTestCase


class UsersTestCase(BaseApiTestCase):

    def test_get_user_account(self):

        # ...Create a test user, login as test user...

        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('api:users-detail', kwargs={'email': 'test@user.com'}),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertStatusCode(response, 200)
```

I get the error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'users-detail' with keyword arguments '{'email': 'test@user.com'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/users/(?P<email>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/users/(?P<email>[^/.]+)/$']
```

It's my understanding that the `[^/.]+` regex should match `test@user.com`.

Although reverse() should do this for me, I've also tried url-encoding the @ symbol, as in:

```
reverse('api:users-account', kwargs={'email': 'test%40user.com'}),
```

Running `manage.py show_urls` reveals that the URL is available:

```
...
/api/users/<email>/ api.views.users.UserViewSet api:users-detail
...
```

**Why can't django's reverse() system find the url match?**

EDIT:
I'm using ViewSets as normal with DRF's routers, so `urls.py` isn't super relevant, but for posterity here's the relevant part:

```
from rest_framework import routers, permissions
from api import views
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.users.UserViewSet, base_name='users')
```

Comment: Please show your actual urls.py.

Comment: Added, thankyou @DanielRoseman

Comment: What if you just pass the value as "test" instead of URL encoded version of @?

Comment: @dan-klasson in that case the URL resolved correctly, but of course the object is not found. Now accepted the answer below, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the `@`, it is the `.`. That's because the default regex the DRF router uses for parameters is `[^/.]+`, which specifically excludes dots.

You should be able to override this by setting `lookup_value_regex` on the viewset:

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_value_regex = r'[^/]+'
```

Comment: FTW! Thank you for your time, Daniel, this worked very well.